# Java Word Guess Game check valid word

Tags: java, string, file-io

I am writing a word guessing game, where the computer chooses a 5 letter word at random from a txt file. Each round the player guesses a 5 letter word if the guess isn't correct the computer says how many letter the guess had in common with the "secret" word.

How to check if the word is in the 'dictionary' (a txt file of permissible words)?

```
 // is word in the dictionary?
 public boolean isValidWord(String word) { 
     //see if string inputted is in the dictionary 

}
```

Comment: In the future, please show your best good faith attempt to solve this problem with your question.

Comment: Yea totally understandable, I am still new to java and have been looking at a blank screen for a bit and decided it was time to post a question. Thank you!

Comment: Even a bad attempt is better than no attempt -- otherwise how will we know what assumptions you may be making that are wrong? Else how will we know what logic or compilation errors you might be running into? Also, this information is required on this site for homework questions, and this is true whether or not this is for homework or home work.

Comment: Not everyone is a genius like you, I know it is a elementary question but we all have to start somewhere..

Comment: Totally understandable. That being said I will flag the question to be deleted. Thank you.

Comment: ............you can't delete it and shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this:
One is that you can read in the dictionary once, hold it in memory as follows, and then do a lookup to see if the word is there

```
 Scanner scanner=new Scanner("FileNameWithPath");
 List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
 while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
     list.add(scanner.nextLine()); 
 }
```

Or similarly with a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/text"));
String str;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
    list.add(str);
}
```

Now your method is a simple check of is the String in the list.

Comment: I already have a buffered reader set up to read in all the words to an ArrayList so do I need the scanner?

Comment: Nope, that works just as well.

Comment: So I would just not use the scanner and instead set up my BufferedReader?

Comment: See above, added the general idea of what it would look like with a BufferedReader

Answer (score 1):

Use java8's new features!

```
// read all lines
return !Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))

    // search matches
    .filter(w -> w.equals(word))

    // any hit?
    .findAny()
    .isEmpty();
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use java 8 as this is a homework assignment.